# show page as a popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, popup

is there any solution that when i acces a normal page it will be loaded in a popup if the user has javascript activated?
So,can i make a normal page a popup? Using a jquery plugin for example?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, for sure you can have pages as popup when js is active.

Check [jQuery bPopUp plugin](http://dinbror.dk/bpopup/). It's simple to implement, and quite interesting in features.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[shadowbox](http://www.shadowbox-js.com/) and [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) are two of my favorites, free for non-commercial use, and not too expensive otherwise. Look at the 'iframe' options for a popup page.